# Runtime Exception in do in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

I am having trouble in getting results from an activity in `asynctask`. Eclipse is showing **runtime exception on doInBackground()**. When I changed the constructor it gave **null pointer exception**.
Please help me getting my result.

```
   public class DataCtrl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{


      int position;
      Context context;
      String strValue;
      String data = null;
      public AsyncResponse delegate=null;
      android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction myft;
      double lat;
      double longi;

      LocationCtrl gps;
      public DataCtrl(int position, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft, Context con){
          this.position = position;
          this.myft = ft;
          context = con;
          gps = new LocationCtrl();
      }


    @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            double lat = 0;
            gps.turnGPSOn();
            gps.getMyCurrentLocation();
            Location loc = gps.getLastKnownLocation(context);
            if (loc != null) { 
                lat = loc.getLatitude();
                longi = loc.getLongitude();
            }
            Log.i("lat", Double.toString(lat));
            if(data == null) {
                data = GET("http://twyst.in/api/v2/data/28/77");
                return data;
            }
            else {
                return data;
            }
        }

      public static String GET(String url){
          InputStream inputStream = null;
          String result = "";
          try {
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

              inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

              if(inputStream != null)
                  result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
              else
                  result = "Did not work!";

          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
          }

          return result;
      }

      // convert inputstream to String
      private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
          BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
          String line = "";
          String result = "";
          while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
              result += line;

          inputStream.close();
          return result;

      }
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

      // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

          setData(result, position);

     }

      public void setData(String result, int pos) {
          Fragment fragment = null;
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.putString("data", result);

          switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    Fragment forme= new ForMeActivity();
                    forme.setArguments(bundle);
                    myft.replace(R.id.mainContent, forme);
                    myft.commit();
                             break;
                case 1:
                    Fragment my= new MyTwystActivity();
                    my.setArguments(bundle);
                    myft.replace(R.id.mainContent, my);
                    myft.commit();
                             break;
                case 2:
                    Fragment near= new NearByActivity();
                    near.setArguments(bundle);
                    myft.replace(R.id.mainContent, near);
                    myft.commit();
                             break;
               default:
                          break;
          }
    }
  }

public class LocationCtrl extends Activity {

private boolean gps_enabled=false;
private boolean network_enabled=false;
Location location;
Double MyLat, MyLong;
Context context;

TextView textView2,textView3;
Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
/** Method to turn on GPS **/

public void turnGPSOn(){
    try
    {    

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), 
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);   

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);          
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);

     }

    }

      catch (Exception e) {          


      }

  }

    // Method to turn off the GPS

     public void turnGPSOff(){

      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

      String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), 

      Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

     if(provider.contains("gps")) { //if gps is enabled

        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}  


     @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {

      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      super.onDestroy();

      turnGPSOff();

   }


     void getMyCurrentLocation() { 

     LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) 

             getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

      LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();

   try{gps_enabled=locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}
   catch(Exception ex){}          
   try{network_enabled=locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}
   catch(Exception ex){}

   //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled

   //if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)

       //return false;

   if(gps_enabled){
       locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);             

   }

   if(gps_enabled){
       location=locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

   }         

   if(network_enabled && location==null){

       locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);            

   } 
   if(network_enabled && location==null)    {
       location=locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

   }


    if (location != null) {         


    MyLat = location.getLatitude();

    MyLong = location.getLongitude();

    } 
    else {

     Location loc= getLastKnownLocation(this);

    if (loc != null) { 

       MyLat = loc.getLatitude();

       MyLong = loc.getLongitude();

   }

}


 locManager.removeUpdates(locListener); // removes the periodic updates from location listener 

 try

{

 Geocoder geocoder; 

 List<Address> addresses;

 geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

 addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(MyLat, MyLong, 1);

}

catch (Exception e)

{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
 textView2.setText(""+MyLat);
 textView3.setText(""+MyLong);

  }
   public Location getLastKnownLocation(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Location location = null;
        LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService("location");
        List<?> list = locationmanager.getAllProviders();
        boolean i = false;
        Iterator<?> iterator = list.iterator();
       do
        {               
            if(!iterator.hasNext())
               break; 
            String s = (String)iterator.next();
            if (i != false && !locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(s))  
             continue;
             Location location1 = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(s);
             if(location1 == null)
                 continue;
             if(location != null)
           {

                float f = location.getAccuracy();
                float f1 = location1.getAccuracy();
                if(f >= f1)

                 {

                    long l = location1.getTime();
                    long l1 = location.getTime();
                    if(l - l1 <= 600000L)

               continue;

          }

     }

            location = location1;

            i = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(s);

        } while(true);

        return location;  
}
```

}

**Logcat:**

```
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3536)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at com.twyst.android.LocationCtrl.getMyCurrentLocation(LocationCtrl.java:93)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at com.twyst.android.DataCtrl.doInBackground(DataCtrl.java:72)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at com.twyst.android.DataCtrl.doInBackground(DataCtrl.java:1)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-10 09:04:23.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     ... 4 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener, AsyncResponse {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView listView;
private String[] menus;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//  dataCtrl.delegate = this;
    menus = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, 
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                R.string.drawer_open, 
                R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

        }
    };

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menus));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    updateDisplay(0);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerListener.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, menus[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    updateDisplay(position);
}

public void updateDisplay(int position) {
    selectItem(position);
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myfm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction myft = myfm.beginTransaction();
    new DataCtrl(position, myft, this).execute();
}

public void selectItem(int position) {

    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(menus[position]);
    //selectItem(pos);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);
}

public void setTitle (String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public void getData(String output, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: please paste your logcat

Comment: I did add all permissions.

Comment: `System services not available to Activities before onCreate()` : Do you have a constructor in your activity class ? Please post the activity class.

Comment: I made a constructor but then it showed NullPointerException.

Comment: Where do you create your AsyncTask?

Comment: In your AsyncTask, to get Activity you need to get it from context of that activity instead of creating constructor of that activity.See below answer.

Comment: @GaganJawa is still the same? Please see new logcat exception,I think it will be different.

Comment: ClassCast exception it is now.

Comment: @GaganJawa means your first problem has been solved.And always post new problem with new question.And accept answer which helped

Comment: okay.!! I am new here so don't know all the customs and btw i have posted my MainActivity class too.

Comment: @GaganJawa Ok,So post your new problem with new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access some system level service even before the `onCreate()` method in the activity.

Please remove any constructors from your Activity and move the processing inside the constructor to your `onCreate()` Method.

Edit 1 :

So, you're using the constructor of the activity to be able to access the activity methods such as `turnGPSOn()` etc but these methods require system services for fetching the location. So, when you create an object of the Activity Class, you get the exception because when you activity hasn't been ***created*** yet but the code inside the Activity constructor tries to call system related services.

Solution : You should move every GPS Related task to your Activity. Eg. The turning on GPS method should be called inside the onCreate() method of your activity. So basically, there are a whole lot of things incorrect with your code. I'd suggest you to re write using the example below.

Simple Example :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
         * Turn on GPS Here. Basically everything that need to do before your
         * network connection should go here.
         */

        // Call your async task
        new GPSTask().execute();

    }

    private class GPSTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            /** Make network request here */
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            /**
             * Update Fragments here. 
             * To be able to access variables from the MainActivity. 
             * Declare them as instance variables;
             */

            tv.setText("onPostExecute");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When I move my processing it showing @ expected on void

Comment: Can you post your activity class. If not, just post the constructor.  It's difficult to find the issue without seeing the code.

Comment: i have already posted LocationCtrl.java is my activity class.

Comment: Yes I did @GiruBhai but it is still the same.

Comment: @GaganJawa Check Edit 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your AsyncTask, to get `Activity` you need to get it from `context` of that activity instead of creating constructor of that activity.

Because `Context` is not available in the Activities Constructor, it is only available in the `Activity.onCreate()` method and beyond.

So in `DataCtrl` constructor change

```
gps = new LocationCtrl();
```

to

```
gps = (Activity)context;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this ( for finding your location only)

In your Main Activity:

```
public LocationClient mLocationClient;
ProgressDialog pd;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, container, false);
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getActivity(), this, this);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.locButton).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                                "Finding you!!!", false);
                        getAddress(v);

                    }

                });
```

The getAddress Method:

```
public void getAddress(View v) {
    // In Gingerbread and later, use Geocoder.isPresent() to see if a
    // geocoder is available.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD
            && !Geocoder.isPresent()) {
        // No geocoder is present. Issue an error message
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_geocoder_available,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (servicesConnected()) {
        // Turn the indefinite activity indicator on
        // Start the background task
        GetAddressTask getAddressTask = new GetAddressTask(getActivity(),
                mLocationClient, pd);
        getAddressTask.delegate = this;
        getAddressTask.execute(currentLocation);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "servicesConnected() == false",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Async Class GetAddressTask:

```
public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
ProgressDialog pd;

protected String doInBackground() {
   // Show user progress        
   pd.show();       
   // Get the current location
   Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
   Lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
   Lng = currentLocation.getLongitude();

   // Now do whatever else!
}

protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
    delegate.processFinished(result);
    // Do other stuff
    // Kill Progress Dialog;
    pd.hide();
}
```